# Validation message helper or retrieving validation error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation

P.S: I've been working with Ruby for less than 48 hours, so expect me to be dumb!

I have set up validation on a model which all works fine. However I want to modify the message retuned by the uniqueness constraint. The message needs to be returned by a method which does some additional processing.

So for example if i try to create a new user model which the "name" attribute set to "bob", and the bob named account already exists, i want to display a message like "Bob isn't available, click here to view the current bob's account".

So the helper method will lookup the current bob account, get the localised string, and do the usual string placement of the localised string, placing the name, link to account and any other information i want into the message.

Essentially i want something like:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :text, :message => self.uniquefound()

def uniquefound()
  return "some string i can make up myself with #{self.name}'s info in it"
end
```

No doubt that's completely wrong...

If this isn't possible, i've found i can use `users.errors.added?` to detect if the name attribute has a unique error added, from there i can probably do some hash manipulation to remove the unique error, and place my own in there either in an "after_validation" callback or in the controller... haven't worked out exactly how to do that, but that's my fallback plan.

So, is there a way of providing a class method callback for the message, AND either passing the current model to that method (if its a static method) or calling it so `self` inside that method is the model being validated.

**Update**

Trawling through the rails sourcecode, i have found this private method that is called during adding an error to the error class

```
private
    def normalize_message(attribute, message, options)
      case message
      when Symbol
        generate_message(attribute, message, options.except(*CALLBACKS_OPTIONS))
      when Proc
        message.call
      else
        message
      end
    end
  end
```

So if i pass a method as the message, i presume that this method is used to call my function/method and get teh return data. However it appears it's not called in the scope of the current object, nor does it pass in the object for which the error pertains...

So, if my digging is on the right path, it appears that calling a method on the current object to the message, or calling a static method passing the object, is not possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this if you really need this functionality.

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
   ....
   validate :unique_name


   def unique_name
     original_user = User.where("LOWER(name) = ?", name.downcase)
     if original_user
       message = "#{name} is not available "
       message << ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to("Click Here",user_path(original_user))
       message << "to view the current #{name}'s account."
       errors.add(:name,message)
     end
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

with a Proc Object instead

```
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
   ....
   validates_uniqueness_of :name, message: Proc.new{|error,attributes| User.non_unique(attributes[:value]) }


   def self.non_unique(name)
     original_user = User.where("LOWER(name) = ? ", name.downcase)
     message = "#{name} is not available "
     message << ActionController::Base.helpers.link_to("Click Here",Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.user_path(original_user))
     message << "to view the current #{name}'s account."
   end
end
```

These will both add the following error message to :name

```
"Name Bob is not available <a href=\"/users/10\">Click Here</a>to view the current Bob's account."
```

Comment: yeah i did look at the possibility of doing my own unique validation which would then allow me to do whatever i liked with the message. Guess i was hoping for something more like a callback. Currently trying to see if i can locate the `:taken` message in the messages, and replace it during `after_validation`, but since the messages hash is only readbale, i've got to use whatever methods the class provides i guess. Which probably means grabbing the entire array of errors for the attribute, locate and remove the value matching `:taken` then insert a new value

Comment: Okay well it has the same exact effect but I have added a method for a Proc object which seems to fit your needs as well and is closer to your original question

Comment: Ha i guess it does have the same effect, since it still has to query for the original account regardless. But it strangely feel like the more appropriate way to use a callback for the message since thats what i want to modify, rather than handling the unique constraint myself completely (not that it ends up any different, so maybe im just being silly). Anyway, thanks for your help! Guess i'll start googling and work out where the two arguments are being specified from, as i couldn't find any indication in the rails source where the attributes were passed to the callback function.